# Error en aplicacion Laravel: could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream en Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp, laravel-8

estoy empesando a desarrollar con laravel en Ubuntu 20.4, logre intalarlo con composee, al crear un proyecto nuevo, y al abrirel local host me sale el siguiente problema:

UnexpectedValueException

The stream or file **"/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/storage/logs/laravel.log"** could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: **Permiso denegado**

http://localhost:8080/test/public/

como servidor local de apache opte primeramente por usar Lampp, luego me instale un servidor apache php, en ambos servidores me sale el mismo problema.

eh echo proyectos web pequeños con php y no tuve este problema.

estoy usando laravel 8 y el php correspondiente como indica la documentación de laravel

si podrían ayudarme se los agredeceria de antemano

Comment: Debes de darle los permisos correspondientes probablemente creaste el proyecto con root y lo estas tratando de ejecutar con tu usuario

Comment: Algo parecido se menciona [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened) quiza eso te aporte algo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me paso lo mismo en una nueva instalacion que hice recientemente de laravel 7.30.1

Solo tienes que colocarte dentro del directorio donde instalaste laravel (laravel7) en mi caso, y abrir tu terminal y ejecutar lo siguiente `sudo chmod 777 storage -R` .

El directorio "storage" es donde guarda los logs, algunas sessiones entre otros archivos.

Esto succede porque laravel necesita el permiso adecuado para escribir los logs, sesiones, etc. y tu servidor no lo permite por defecto, asi que tienes que darle los permisos manualmente con el comando de arriba.

777 significa que puede leer, escribir y ejecutar, si solo quieres que lea y escriba solo pon 775 o 776 pero te recomiendo que pongas 777 para estar seguro que tiene todos lor permisos.

Comment: Me funcionó usandolo en la carpeta raíz del proyecto. Gracias!.

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 storage